# Interior region bounded by two curves

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I understand to find the area of the interior region bounded by two curves you take the definite integrals of the two curves for the selected regions and you minus the larger area by the smaller area.

However for this question I'm confused about what this "I" means and how this affects the question. Could someone walk me through this please?

The question is :

Let $I:= \iint{2dA},$

where $D$ is the interior of the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2$ and $y=x^3$
with $x>=0$ and $y>=0$

The value of $I$ is?

Comment: Is I evaluated over D?

Comment: Not quite sure, this is all I have for the question and the answer of the entire question is 1/6

Comment: Ok, I'll try to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curves $y = x^2$ and $y=x^3$ intersect a x=0,1 for x>=0

If we find the values of $x^2$ and $x^3$ for $0<=x<=1$, we can find that  $x^2>=x^3$

Now for the double integral,$\int\int_D dA = \int\int_D dxdy$, we have the limits as, $0<=x<=1$ and $x^3<=y<=x^2$

So,

$\int\int_D dA = \int^1_{0}\int^{x^2}_{x^3} dxdy = \int^1_{0} dx(y)^{x^2}_{x^3} = \int^1_{0} (x^2 - x^3)dx$ $$= (\frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4})^1_0= (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}) = \frac{1}{12}$$

Now, $I = 2\int\int_D dA = 2.\frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{6}$